# How to insert php array elements into multiple rows in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, mysqli-multi-query

I have a php array with 100 elements in it. How can I insert the entire array at once in mysql. Currently, I am inserting 1 element at a time using a loop, as below.

```
for($x=1;$x<=100;$x++){
    mysqli_query($Conn,"INSERT INTO mytable (slno) VALUES ('$myarray[x]')");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this must work:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO mytable (slno) VALUES ";

for($x=1;$x<=100;$x++){
    $query .= "('$myarray[x]')";

    if($x < 100)
    {
        $query .= ",";
    }
    else
    {
        $query .= ";";
    }
}

mysqli_query($Conn, $query);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your can insert multiple rows at once, with a single INSERT. Your MySQL request should look like this:

```
INSERT INTO
mytable
(slno)

VALUES
(1),
(2),
(3),
...
```

You could use a loop to build a values array and then implode it with a comma:

```
$values = array();

foreach( $myarray as $value)
{
    $values[] = '('.$value.')';
}

$query = "INSERT INTO mytable (slno) VALUES ".implode( ',', $values );
```

Comment: Is this method efficient and the right way to do? Sorry I am new to programming.

Comment: I would not say it's *the* "right" way, but it works. As to effiency, you now have only one MySQL INSERT query as opposed to how many you had before. So in that respect it is more efficient.

Comment: I think there is something wrong with the last line in code you wrote. There is a  " (double quote) missing.

Comment: You're right, in fact I removed the last double quote because it is not needed (it was not missing it was added by mistake).